# how to use maya object in android?

Tags: android, animation, maya

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rendering Maya animation on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690595/rendering-maya-animation-on-android)

want to use maya object in android. is there any tool & script which will help me to use maya object in android project so that I can render that object in maya & try out to develop simple game

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690595/rendering-maya-animation-on-android issue this may help u
Thanks
Aamir

Comment: yes this helped 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690595/rendering-maya-animation-on-android
Thanks to @Amir